# ggplot2 color - Displays a different color when specified 'red'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand how ggplot2 handles the aesthetics for color.
The two ggplot commands shown below display different colors.The second command displays a lighter color, and in addition prints a legend. 
I appreciate if anyone can throw some light on this concept.

```
data(iris)

#1st command
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width), color = "red")

#2nd command
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,  color = "red"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`aes()` maps between variables in the input data and visual properties such as color, shape, etc. Therefore, your first command which assigned `"red"` as a `color` outside of `aes()` is correct. Your second command seems incorrect (although it will work without any errors) as you did not match `color` to your `variable` in `aes()`. You can map a variable (e.g., `Species` in `iris` data) to `color` inside of `aes()` such as,

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,  color = Species))
```

I don't know how ggplot2 handles this, but I think you will get the same color for your plot regardless of color names inside of `aes()` in your second command.

For example, those three codes below will plot the same with the same light red color (except the legends).

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,  color = "red"))
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,  color = "black"))
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,  color = "blue"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mapping an aesthetic to a fixed value in `aes`, as in `aes(color = "red")`, essentially creates a variable in the data with only one value, `"red"` and maps color to that. This is sometimes used as a bit of "trick" to produce a legend for a specific layer when the intent is to annotate, but other functions have grown up to handle many of those cases.

Comment: Thanks for the details!